# I keep getting a rendering error when trying to play Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

Every time I log onto the server and it tries to load the resource pack, I get the rendering error seen in this log:

https://paste.ee/p/H1XjV

and here (since it happens with or without the mods and forge):

https://paste.ee/p/v9jS5

Ubuntu 22.10
Linux Kernel 5.19, 6.1 and 6.2 (released today) I tried all three

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Is this a new Minecraft server? Or has it been running without any problems for a while and now you are seeing rendering errors? Have you confirmed that the version of Java is correct?

Comment: Fairly new yes, but it is even happening on a server that has been active for years. I have checked Java version. Currently for newer server 17.0.6, older one running 1.8.361